# How to use shortcut keys to run the current individual cpp file in CLion?

Tags: c++, keyboard-shortcuts, clion, jetbrains-ide, ideavim

I want to clarify that answering is not as simple as pressing <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + F10</kbd>. When using CLion, if I am working on a cpp project, indeed I can directly run the entire project using the aforementioned shortcut. However, it is different when I am editing a single file.

- When I create a new file and want to run it, I have to click on the green triangle on the left side of the main function, and then select the "Run..." option to execute the program. It's really frustrating (although I found that after clicking that triangle, I can use <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + F10</kbd> to run the file).

  [image]
- Another shortcut for running is <kbd>Shift + F10</kbd>. The peculiarity of this shortcut is that regardless of the currently active page, it will run the last executed file. To run the current file using this shortcut, I either have to repeat the previous method or open a window to select a run configuration, which is quite cumbersome.

I hope to find a solution that closely resembles the functionality of clicking the green triangle (preferably native), which means I don't want to use terminal commands for compilation and execution like the "Run Code" feature in VSCode.

- The IDE action corresponding to <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + F10</kbd> is "Run Class," while the action corresponding to <kbd>Ctrl + Shift</kbd> is simply "Run." This information can be found using the IdeaVim's "track action id" feature. I tried to achieve this by editing the keymap in Vim, but I was not successful. The main issue lies in switching the run configuration.
- IdeaVim was not able to replicate all Vim commands perfectly. Its support for `:let` and `:echo` is not as flawless. The persistence of a purely keyboard-driven workflow makes one want to eliminate almost all unnecessary mouse work...

I have added some shortcut keys for editing the Run configuration (and since I don't know how to automate this process with variables, I had to add another shortcut key to retrieve the file path for filling in the "Source file" option). This way, I can manually create a Run configuration and then select it to run the current file.

Indeed, doing it this way is certainly very cumbersome.

[image]

Comment: 1) `Shift + F10` is for executing the currently selected Run/Debug Configuration. Useful when your app has many files but you need to run certain main file that executes the code in the edited file. 2) RE `$FilePath$` -- not every Run/Debug Configuration supports such macros. Normally such a file will have a button to list and insert macros (normally will have a `+` icon (like see on a screenshot here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/run-debug-configuration.html#change-template).

Comment: 3) The Run/Debug Configuration dropdown -- the one that lists them on on a toolbar. It should have the "Current File" entry as well. Does CLion has one? An example from PhpStorm v2023.1.4: https://i.imgur.com/dn7UL8D.png

Comment: I believe I have temporarily resorted to a less elegant solution. I have defined a hotstring 'fh' using AutoHotkey to create and populate a Run/Configuration configuration.

Every time I press 'fh' within that window, it triggers automatic filling. Once the filling is complete, the current run configuration will be set accordingly.

As for switching to a CPP file, I have to open the configuration selection interface (using 'j' in my case), and then select the corresponding configuration.

Comment: This is my code:
- ideavimrc


```
map <leader>j <Action>(editRunConfigurations) 
map <leader>n <Action>(CopyContentRootPath)
```

- ahkscript
```
#HotIf WinActive("Run/Debug Configurations") && WinActive("ahk_exe clion64.exe")
:*:fh::{
 Interval := 50
 Send "{Alt Down}{Insert}{Alt Up}"
 Sleep 200
 Send "{Enter}"
 Sleep 500
 Loop 6
 {
  Send "{Tab}"
  Sleep Interval
 }
 Send "{Ctrl Down}av{Ctrl Up}"
 Sleep Interval
 Send "{Enter}"
}
```